# jquery ajax call showing as invalid url

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I am trying to get Response from server url written as

```
<Server IP>:<Port>/getcategories
```

Following is jquery ajax call

```
        $("#restcall").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('submit admin login form');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType : 'json',
                headers : {
                    'key' : 'nJ36k2fTng+BXPI47wvh+he6tABaD2eheqf4OtOj5oauWgn3vA=', 
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                url: '<Serverip>:<port>/getcategories',
                success : function (msg) {
                    conosle.log('sucess');
                },
                error : function(msg){
                    console.log(msg.status + ',' +msg.statusText);  
                }
            });
            console.log('done done');
        });
```

After running the above code my server url not called, instead error function is called with following message:

```
0,SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
```

I am able to get response with above url using postman.

Any suggestions ?

EDIT:

After adding http:// before Server IP, I am getting following error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://103.241.181.83:9126/getcategories. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: if you're specifying an IP (or a hostname), I think you might need to provide either "http://" or "https://" (as appropriate) in front of it?

Comment: @ADyson: Updated the Post.

Comment: For the new error, you need to enable CORS on the server because this is treated as a cross-domain request.

Comment: hmm. I had less control over remote server. If there is any workaround possible without modifying server files, that would be great. Thanks anyway.

Comment: the only workaround is to make the request outside an ajax context. So, if your own web application has a server-side (e.g. .NET, PHP, node), use the tools on your own server-side to make the request to the remote server, and then return the response to your client-side. So the flow would be Your page -> ajax request -> your server -> standard HTTP request -> remote server. Your server can directly return the response from the remote server back to your ajax request.